# How to specify monospace fonts for cross platform Qt applications?

Tags: qt, fonts

Is there a platform independent way to specify a fixed width font for a Qt widget ?

If I set the font to "Monospace" in Designer on Linux, it is not found on Windows and Arial is used instead.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can retrieve the system's default fixed font using QFontDatabase's systemFont(..) function.
It was introduced in Qt 5.2.

Example:

```
const QFont fixedFont = QFontDatabase::systemFont(QFontDatabase::FixedFont)
```

Comment: Actually, this didn't work on Qt 5 on Linux, but it may be due to some fontconfig misconfiguration in our static Qt build; however, the `setStyleHint` method did work.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Which Linux? It also didn't work for me on KDE Neon 16.04.

Comment: @Silicomancer: eeh who knows; it was surely some KDE version, either the one of Kubuntu 16.04 or 14.04.

Answer (score 59):

You can use the [style hint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qfont.html#StyleHint-enum) property of QFont:

```
QFont font("Monospace");
font.setStyleHint(QFont::TypeWriter);
```

If the font cannot be found (which happens with Monospace on Windows), Qt's [font matching algorithm](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qfont.html#fontmatching) tries to find a font that matches the given style hint.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not `QFont::Monospace` ?

Comment: A helpful addendum: that code only works if you pass a family name to the QFont constructor. Otherwise, it will use the default font family, which will be variable width, which then overrides the style hint. I had to do this, `QFont font("");`, when I didn't have a specific monospace font to request.

Comment: @kralyk I was curious, too, and I tried on Windows and I noticed that `QFont::Monospace` will not result in a monospace font, while `TypeWriter` will. Can't really explain why, though :(

Comment: (Note, the following is valid for PyQt, I cannot test it for C++ but it should work in the same way) In order to get a font that is proportional to the default one, it's better to use the application font and then set the font family string: `font = QFont()` `font.setFamily('monospace')`; it may still be necessary to set the style hint before the family.

Answer (score 20):

For all widgets that accept Rich Text you can simply put it into a `pre` block, i.e. `<pre>This is my Text</pre>`. It will then use the systems monospace font.

Comment: I tried this in my program and it worked, but it also added a line break following the pre tag.  I didn't know how to get rid of that so I tried <font face="monospace">text</font> instead and that worked!  I haven't verified, though, that my solution is portable.

Comment: Or `<code>` if you want the text to wrap.

Answer (score 7):

I use Courier in Qt on both Linux and Windows.