# Text in QTextEdit is distorted

Tags: pyside, python-unicode, qtextedit

I have a `QTextEdit` in which I want to set some text *(unicode)* that has been generated by an ASCII Art text renderer. Everything works fine, except that the `QTextEdit` is distorting the text. The screenshot shows the same unicode text variable set in the `QTextEdit` via `setText()` and logged to the console, where it is displayed correctly.

---

[image: QTextEdit distorts text]

---

It doesn't seem to matter if I use `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit`, or if I am setting the text via `setText(ascii_art_text)` or `setPlainText(ascii_art_text)`. I'm using PySide here, however I suspect that isn't of too much interest in this case.

---

*Any ideas how to fix that distortion?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of your example, it appears that your `QTextEdit` is not using a monospaced font which is what terminals and text editors typically use. Create a [QFont](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QFont.html) using a monospaced font. E.g.,

```
# Specific Windows monospaced font.
font = QFont("Courier New")
```

According to Torsten Marek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835938/369450) in [How to specify monospace fonts for cross platform Qt applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1468022/369450), you can get a cross platform monospaced font with:

```
font = QFont("Monospace")
font.setStyleHint(QFont.TypeWriter)
```

Once you've determined your font, assign it to your `QTextEdit`:

```
text_edit.setCurrentFont(font)
```