# How to make QPlainTextEdit look like a .txt file?

Tags: python, pyqt, prettytable

I have a QPlainTextEdit which shows some information in tabular form, and I added the option to save it as a .txt file. I built the table with [prettytable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable). When I open the .txt file, it looks nice, just how I want it to look like. However, in my GUI, QPlainTextEdit shows it all unaligned. How can I make it look like in the .txt?

How I want it to look

[image]

How QPlainTextEdit shows it

[image]

Comment: Use a monospace font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no such a thing as "showing as a txt file", as txt files don't contain formatting information.

Anyway, what you actually want is to set the font of your `QPlainTextEdit` to some fixed-width (or monospace) font; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1468022/214671) to see how to obtain one portably.