# Print PrettyTable data to QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qplaintextedit, prettytable

My setup is Windows 10, Python 3.7, PyQt5

The goal is to print a **formatted table** to a **QPlainTextEdit**.

I have some data in a **PrettyTable** object. When I print this data to stdout, the table gets printed perfectly! But when printing to QPlainTextEdit (using table.get_string())... it looses the correct format.

A small code to show the issue:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QLabel, QPlainTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from prettytable import PrettyTable

class Example(QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    hbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

qpt = QPlainTextEdit(self)
qpt.setReadOnly(True)

x = PrettyTable()
x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]
x.add_rows(
    [
        ["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5],
        ["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4],
        ["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7],
        ["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5],
        ["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8],
        ["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9],
        ["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4],
    ]
)
qpt.appendPlainText(x.get_string())

hbox.addWidget(qpt)

self.resize(400, 300)
self.setWindowTitle('QPlainTextEdit')
self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

How to achieve the correct format for the table?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872430/how-to-make-qplaintextedit-look-like-a-txt-file) post.

Keeping it short:

```
font = QFont("Monospace")
font.setStyleHint(QFont.TypeWriter)
my_plain_text_edit.setFont(font)
```